# Multiple joins to the same table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables Profile_Appointments and Profile.

Each record in the profile table has a Profile_key and a Profile_Type_Key in addition to other profile data - first name, last name, etc.

Rep's have Profile_Type 4, Customer's have Profile_Type 6

```
 PROFILE TABLE
 Profile_Key    Profile_Type_key    First_Name     Last_Name
  1234                 4              John            Smith
  8765                 6              Mike            Jones
```

The Profile_Appointment table holds two records for each appointment one with the Rep's 
Profile_Key the other with the customer's Profile_Key

```
 Appointment_Key        Profile_Key     
     10                    1234
     10                    8765
```

The appointment_key refers to the Appointment table.

I need make a query that results in one record for each appointment and has both the rep and customer's data from the Profile table

```
 THE RESULT I WANT
 Appointment_Key  Profile_Key Rep    Profile_Key Customer
    10                1234                    8765
```

This is the query that's not working...

```
  select appointment_key, p.profile_key as Rep, p2.profile_key as Customer, p.firs_name,p2.first_name from profile_appointment pa

  join profile p 
  on p.profile_key = pa.profile_key

  join profile p2
  on p2.profile_key = pa.profile_key

  where p.profile_type_key = '4' or p2.profile_type_key = '6'
```

What I get is:

```
 Appointment_Key      Rep      Customer     Rep      Customer
    10                1234      1234        John       John
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing.
Thanks.

Comment: You appear to only be selecting a single row at a time from Profile appointment, so you will only have one Profile_Key to join on.

Comment: Wouldn't you accomplish the very same thing sticking to just one table with the same where clause???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to satisfy both conditions so you need AND instead of OR

```
    select pa.appointment_key, p.profile_key as Rep, p2.profile_key as Customer, 
        p.first_name as RepName,p2.first_name as CustomerName
from profile_appointment pa    
join profile_appointment pa2 on pa.appointment_key = pa2.appointment_key
join profile p    on p.profile_key = pa.profile_key    and  p.profile_type_key = '4'
join profile p2   on p2.profile_key = pa2.profile_key   and  p2.profile_type_key = '6'
```

Comment: Neither of these options return the desired result.  Just replacing OR with AND yields 0 results.  The second query using left joins is almost correct, but returns two rows, one with rep data and the other with customer data.

Comment: YOu are right, I missed that appointment had two records. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a1.appointment_key, a1.profile_key rep, a2.profile_key customer
  FROM appointment a1
  INNER JOIN profile p1 ON a1.profile_key = p1.profile_key AND p1.profile_type_key = 4
  INNER JOIN appointment a2 ON a1.appointment_key = a2.appointment_key
  INNER JOIN profile p2 ON a2.profile_key = p2.profile_key AND p2.profile_type_key = 6
```

EDIT: You might find nested selects more readable:

```
SELECT reps.appointment_key, reps.profile_key rep, customers.profile_key customer
  FROM (
    SELECT appointment.*
      FROM appointment
      INNER JOIN profile ON appointment.profile_key = profile.profile_key AND profile_type_key = 4
  ) reps
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT appointment.*
      FROM appointment
      INNER JOIN profile ON appointment.profile_key = profile.profile_key AND profile_type_key = 6
  ) customers ON reps.appointment_key = customers.appointment_key
```